# Analysis and writing up results

Tags: spss, multivariate-analysis, chi-squared-test, bivariate

I am doing research for my Masters studies and am battling a bit with the statistical side of my study. I used a survey and have captured all the data into SPSS. I have no statistical background, I would thus need a bit of advice on how to interpret / analyse results. 
I am making use of Chi-Square test to look at relationships between categorical and other categorical variables and Correlation test for relationships between ordinal and other ordinal variables. Because of the dichotomy, I am making use of Binomial logistic regression. What I don't know is how to write results up and analyse results. For example a correlation of .000 is highly significant, but how do I word it? And what if almost all the results in the table are highly significant? For example people who agree that shopping online is safe also agree that the internet is trustworthy. Kind of expected - the result is significant but rather obvious.

Comment: When you say "For example a correlation of .000 is highly significant, but how do I word it?", you appear to have it exactly backward.

Comment: Do you mean "For example a correlation that has a p-value of 0.000 is highly significant?".  In which case, it is also worth looking at the magnitude of the correlation as well.  Are you able to show us a small piece of the SPSS output?

Answer (score 2):

The general structure of the thesis will probably be dictated by your school; can you get a previous thesis that had similar statistics and follow that for form? Note that many schools follow APA format for writing statistical results; the [APA manual](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_4?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=apa%20manual%207th%20edition&sprefix=apa%20,aps,194) is quite detailed and there are also help guides for it (all at the link).

In terms of your particular study, it would help us a lot if you could tell us what you are studying. You can report obvious findings; to show that you knew that they were obvious, you can say something like "As expected, height was related to weight, r = XXX, p = YYY, 95%CI = QQQ to RRR". In the discussion section, such findings would merit little discussion.

It is not a problem if nearly all the results are statistically significant; it is a problem if the effect sizes are not in line with what you expected (or what the literature shows). However, such findings can be very interesting as well.  Your analysis section should follow your research questions; that is, each research question should have one or more analytic results to answer it (and to test any related hypotheses).